# Getting mouse position on scroll event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can I get **mouse position** on scrolling event?

If I have a code:

```
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
        console.log("scroll");
        // mouse position (x,y) ?
    });
```

Comment: Scroll event parameters are offsets not mouse positions. You get mouse positions for mousemove event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953144/how-do-i-get-the-offset-top-value-of-an-element-without-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
    console.log("scroll");
    console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY); //relative to window
    console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY); //relative to window
});
```

Comment: undefined undefined for x y

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
   console.log("scroll");
   var domElem = event.target;

   var nbPXFromTop = domElem.scrollTop; //nb of pixel from the top 
   var nbPxFromLeft = domElem.scrollLeft;
});
```

Comment: OP asks for mouse position