# Getting Table row height from top of a page

Tags: html, html-table

I have a dynamic Table in html.
I can get my table row by below function.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-click="heightChecker(this)" ng-repeat='DFC in DetailsOfFloorsCurrent'<td>blahblah</td></tr>
```

Script:

```
$scope.heightChecker = function (row) {
    alert(row.$index-2);
}
```

I want to get my row height, from top of my page.
I can get my row, but I can't get the height in pixel from top of my page.
Is there any way?
(attention: My table is dynamic with n row and n column.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `offset()`:

```
$('row').offset().top
```

Using that you get the distance from the top.

Comment: Im not using JQUERY & i have no idea about how to use it.
If there is any way to using angularjs or javascript, i will be thanksful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953144/how-do-i-get-the-offset-top-value-of-an-element-without-using-jquery
There is another post asking how to get the offset top, without using jQuery.
There they use angular or javascript.
I think there you can find the answer to your comment.
Hope it's helpful!