# Finding the position of an Element in a html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to get the position of an element in a html page using $document.find. But, it is always undefined.

Here is my code.

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).
controller('myController', function($scope, $document) {

var element = $document.find('my_element');
console.log(element.prop('offsetTop'));
console.log(element.offsetTop);
});
```

And this is html page.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="driversController">
  <div id="my_element">Looping with ng-repeat:</div>
  .......
</div>
```

I do not want to use jquery along with angularjs. P;ease suggest a way to do this in angularjs.Thanks

Comment: jQuery `.offset()` should work

Comment: @PankajParkar  But I did not want to use jquery along with angularjs.How can I do this in angularjs?

Comment: got it.. look at the answer which I've added.. Thanks :-)

Comment: AngularJS jqLite find() - Limited to lookups by tag name. See [Angulars jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jquery `.offset()` to find the position.

```
var offSet = $("#my_element").offset();
console.log(offSet.top);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/o9krfznt/1/

Comment: It works. But I did not want to use jquery along with angularjs. How can I do this in strict angularjs?

Comment: @MukundGandlur you tagged angularjs, also perhaps you should append your question to say specifically not to use angularjs

Comment: @MukundGandlur: If you are looking for pure angular solution , you might wanna take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953144/how-do-i-get-the-offset-top-value-of-an-element-without-using-jquery. Also remove the tag jquery from the question tag.

Comment: Marked this as answer because, the post in your comment helped me.

Answer (score 2):

By having vanilla JavaScript, you could access offset values from DOM by doing `element[0]`.

```
var element = $document.find('my_element');
console.log(element.prop('offsetTop'));
console.log(element[0].offsetTop);
console.log(element[0].offsetLeft);
```

Comment: Its printing "undefined". I will add a plunkr.

Comment: Here is my plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/vKD8DSSdw95WtPq4kUwp.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each element in page until you get to the element you want.

```
        function left_on(el)
        {    
                for (var lx=0, ly=0;
                     el != null;
                     lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.offsetTop, el = el.offsetParent);
            return lx  ;// or ly 
        }
```