# Scroll to element in flexbox container

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, autoscroll

I am trying to autoscroll to an element in a flexbox container.

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="items">
    <div ng-repeat="i in items"  scroll-on-click>
      {{i}} click me to scroll to me!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

app.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, $element) {
      $element.on('click', function() {
        $(".items").animate({scrollTop: $element.offset().top}, "slow");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

It scrolls to the top of the first item clicked, but after that it has a hard time scrolling.  I have had something very similar in a non-flexbox container working.

Here is a plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kq40NiTqBI81KlRJBLHu?p=preview

Any ideas?

Comment: Happening on all browsers? Chrome seems to be working fine.

Comment: Chrome does not work for me.  When I click elements they do not always scroll to the top. Seems like if I start at the top of the list it will scroll correctly.  However if I am in the middle of the list, not so much.

Comment: Consider adding Javascript, jQuery and CSS tags for more attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `offsetTop` property to capture the scroll value of embedded (non-root) DOM elements, like a flexbox. Good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953144/how-do-i-get-the-offset-top-value-of-an-element-without-using-jquery). I'm subtracting 10 to stop the divs from being cut off, do as you wish.

```
$(".items").animate({scrollTop: $element.prop('offsetTop') - 10}, "slow");
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMwZLwnSgZMHTq4Ycekg)

**EDIT:**

To handle a header or other element, flexbox or not, just subtract its height from scrollTo (assigning an id to the header):

```
$(".items")
  .animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $('#' + id).prop('offsetTop') - 
        document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight - 
        10 // Store this as a .constant if it won't change

    }, "slow");
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LH37J6EEy0UX5sDivM9i?p=preview)

Comment: That is working a bit better.  However I am still having problems if I have flex'ed content above the scroll.  See updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kq40NiTqBI81KlRJBLHu?p=preview.  Since its flex'ed I don't really know how how to offset.

Comment: Hi, see my edited answer above. Hope this works for you.